# Grails. Hibernate lazy loading multiple objects

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I'm having difficulties with proxied objects in Grails.
Assuming I've got the following

```
class Order {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="xxx", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "xxx")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "yyy")})
    @OrderBy("id")
      @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
      private List<OrderItem> items;
    } 

class Customer {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "xxx",insertable = false, nullable = false)
    private OrderItem lastItem;

    private Long lastOrderId;
}
```

And inside some controller class

```
//this all happens during one hibernate session.
    def currentCustomer = Customer.findById(id)
//at this point currentCustomer.lastItem is a javassist proxy

def lastOrder = Order.findById(current.lastOrderId)
//lastOrder.items is a proxy
//Some sample actions to initialise collections 
lastOrder.items.each { println "${it.id}"}
```

After the iteration `lastOrder.items` still contains a proxy of `currentCustomer.lastItem`. For example if there are 4 items in the lastOrder.items collection, it looks like this:

- object
- object
- javassist proxy (all fields are null including id field). This is the same object as in currentCustomer.lastItem.
- object

Furthermore, this proxy object has all properties set to null and it's not initialized when getters are invoked. I have to manually call `GrailsHibernateUtils.unwrapIdProxy()` on every single element inside `lastOrder.items` to ensure that there are no proxies inside (which basically leads to EAGER fetching).

This one proxy object leads to some really weird Exceptions, which are difficult to track on testing phase.

Interesting fact: if I change the ordering of the operations (load the order first and the customer second) every element inside `lastOrder.items` is initialized.

The question is: Is there a way to tell Hibernate that it should initialize the collections when they are touched, no matter if any elements from the collection is already proxied in the session?

Comment: If `it` is a proxy then `println "${it.id}"` won't trigger initialization, you have to get a non-ID property for that.

Comment: @IanRoberts  Any reference to official documentation? Cause from my point of view for a proxy object it really makes sense to initialize Id field. Especially in cases where ManyToOne is used (Foreign Key is stored in the parent object)

Comment: A proxy in Hibernate is a holder that knows the ID but nothing else.  It can answer requests to get the ID without having to go the database but when you ask it for anything else it uses the ID (which it already knows) to query the database and load the real object with all its properties populated.  Subsequent method calls on the proxy delegate directly to the underlying object.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misunderstood your comment. The problem is that the id field of the proxy is null (shown in debug view and console logs)

Comment: lastOrder.items is a Collection<OrderItem>, while currentCustomer.lastItem is an Order.  Yet you say that "lastOrder.items still contains a proxy of currentCustomer.lastItem".  Can you clarify what you mean there?

Comment: Does OrderItem have any fields that are themselves references to other entities, either directly or indirectly (through @Embeddables)?

Comment: What's wrong with proxy? What  weird Exceptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what's happening here is an interesting interaction between the first level cache (stored in Hibernate's Session instance) and having different `FetchType` on related objects.

When you load `Customer`, it gets put in to the `Session` cache, along with any objects that are loaded with it.  This includes a proxy object for the `OrderItem` object, because you've got `FetchType.LAZY`.  Hibernate only allows one instance to be associated with any particular ID, so any further operations that would be acting on the `OrderItem` with that ID ***would always be using that proxy***.  If you asked the same `Session` to get that particular `OrderItem` in another way, as you are by loading an `Order` containing it, that `Order` would have the proxy, because of Session-level identity rules.

That's why it 'works' when you reverse the order.  Load the `Order` first, it's collection is `FetchType.EAGER`, and so it (and the first level cache) have fully realized instances of `OrderItem`.  Now load a `Customer` which has it's `lastItem` set to one of the already-loaded `OrderItem` instances and presto, you have a real `OrderItem`, not a proxy.

You can see the identity rules documented in the [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-identity):

> For objects attached to a particular Session... JVM identity for database identity is guaranteed by Hibernate.

All that said, even if you get an `OrderItem` proxy, it should work fine as long as the associated `Session` is still active.  I wouldn't necessarily expect the proxy ID field to show up as populated in the debugger or similar, simply because the proxy handles things in a 'special' way (ie, it's not a POJO).  But it should respond to method calls the same way it's base class would.  So if you have an `OrderItem.getId()` method, it should certainly return the ID when called, and similarly on any other method.  Because it's lazily initialized though, some of those calls may require a database query.

It's possible that the only real problem here is simply that it's confusing to have it so that any particular `OrderItem` could be a proxy or not.  Maybe you want to simply change the relationships so that they're either both lazy, or both eager?

For what it's worth, it's a bit odd that you've got the ManyToMany relationship as `EAGER` and the ManyToOne as `LAZY`.  That's exactly the reverse of the usual settings, so I would at least think about changing it (although I obviously don't know your entire use case).  One way to think about it: If an `OrderItem` is so expensive to fetch completely that it's a problem when querying for `Customer`, surely it's also too expensive to load *all* of them at once?  Or conversely, if it's cheap enough to load all of them, surely it's cheap enough to just grab it when you get a `Customer`?

Comment: that probably explains the situation. Weird Exceptions - the id property is null on the proxy object and proxy itself is not initialized when accessed through collection of elements

Comment: @Funtik ok, i updated my answer with what i think about that, and how you should move forward.  good luck.

Comment: it seems weird at first, but when we load Order object in 95% of the cases we need OrderItems. On the other hand, Customer is used in almost all cases (so we try to optimize the DB hits).

Comment: @Funtik depending on whether OrderItem itself has a collection, you may want to look at [FetchModes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching).  FetchMode.JOIN may solve your DB hits problem while also allowing you to do EAGER fetching with Customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can force eager loading this way or using

```
def lastOrder = Order.withCriteria(uniqueResult: true) {
       eq('id', current.lastOrderId)
       items{}
   }
```

or using HQL query with 'fetch all'